# multiple arguments to `ts-node -r` options

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json, ts-node

I want to add multiple `require` in my `package.json` script before executing using
[ts-node -r](https://typestrong.org/ts-node/docs/options/#require).

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node -r dotenv/config newrelic src/index.ts",
    }
```

It doesn't let me add both "dotenv/config" and "newrelic" at the same time.
But if I use only one of them at a time it works perfectly fine.

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node -r dotenv/config src/index.ts",
    }
```

OR

```js
"scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node -r newrelic src/index.ts",
    }
```

Is there a way I can require both libs?

Answer (score 2):

The `-r` option can be repeated.

Please try the following:

```bash
ts-node -r dotenv/config -r newrelic index.ts
```